# ConTeXt: How do I get multi-level descriptions? The contextgarden example does not work

Tags: lists, indentation, context, description

The following contextgarden example from http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Description to produce a two-level description using ConTeXt doesn't work for me.  The resulting pdf is as if all four items form a flat list rather than a two-level nested list.  Moreover, all of the text ends up aligned to the *right* even though alignment to the left is specified in the ConTeXt code.  How can I get the results that the above URL claims?

The ConTeXt code from the above URL is:

```
\setuppapersize[A5]
\definedescription[descr][
  headstyle=bold, style=normal, align=left, location=hanging, 
  width=broad, margin=1cm]

\starttext
\startdescr{Para}
  This is a shorter item label, and some text that talks about it.
  The text is wrapped into a paragraph, with successive lines indented.

  This is another paragraph under the "Para" item.
  \startdescr{Sub Item}  
    This is a description of an item which is within the "Para" item.
  \stopdescr
  \startdescr{Sub Item} 
    Another Sub Item 
  \stopdescr
\stopdescr
\startdescr{Short}
  A short item that's not part of that really long "Para" item.
\stopdescr

\stoptext
```

ConTeXt version 2014.01.03 00:40 produces a pdf that is schematically like this:

```
Para  This is a shorter item label, and some text
        that talks about it.  The text is wrapped
      into a paragprah, with successive lines in-
                                          dented.
              This is another paragraph under the
                                     "Para" item.

      Sub Item  This is a description of an item
                 which is within the "Para" item.

                      Sub Item  Another Sub Item

 Short  A short item that's not part of that re-
                          ally long "Para" item.
```

Removing the "location=hanging" attribute changes the results to

```
  Para        This is a shorter item label, and
              some text that talks about it.  The
              text is wrapped into a paragprah,
              with successive lines indented.
              This is another paragraph under
              the "Para" item.

  Sub Item    This is a description of an item which
              is within the "Para" item.

  Sub Item    Another Sub Item

  Short       A short item that's not part of that
              really long "Para" item.
```

which looks better but still treats the list as if it were flat.  What I'm looking for is something similar to this:

```
Para    This is a shorter item label, and some
    text that talks about it.  The text is
    wrapped into a paragprah, with successive
    lines indented.
    This is another paragraph under the "Para"
    item.

    Sub Item    This is a description of an
        item which is within the "Para" item.

    Sub Item    Another Sub Item

Short    A short item that's not part of that
    really long "Para" item.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned on the wiki page, in MkIV, you have to use `alternative=hanging`. You also probably want `align=flushleft` rather than `align=left` (which gives ragged left output, see the [FAQ](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/FAQ#Why_does_.5Cstartalignment.5Bright.5D_or_.5Cframed.5Balign.3Dright.5D.7Bsome_text.7D_align_my_text_left_instead_of_right_and_vice_versa.3F)). With these changes, I get:

```
\setuppapersize[A5]
\definedescription
  [descr]
  [
    headstyle=bold, 
    style=normal,
    align=flushleft,
    alternative=hanging, 
    width=broad,
    margin=1cm,
  ]

\starttext
\startdescr{Para}
  This is a shorter item label, and some text that talks about it.
  The text is wrapped into a paragraph, with successive lines indented.

  This is another paragraph under the "Para" item.
  \startdescr{Sub Item}  
    This is a description of an item which is within the "Para" item.
  \stopdescr
  \startdescr{Sub Item} 
    Another Sub Item 
  \stopdescr
\stopdescr
\startdescr{Short}
  A short item that's not part of that really long "Para" item.
\stopdescr

\stoptext
```

which gives what you want:

[image]