# ConTeXt \definedescription: How to get the description's label on a line of its own?

Tags: lists, indentation, context, description

[ConTeXt: How do I get multi-level descriptions? The contextgarden example does not work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223879/context-how-do-i-get-multi-level-descriptions-the-contextgarden-example-does-n) shows how to get nested descriptions, but each description begins on the same line as the label that it describes.  How do I get the description to begin on a new line, so that the label is on a line of its own?

The ConTeXt code described in the abovementioned answer is

```
\setuppapersize[A5]
\definedescription
  [descr]
  [
    headstyle=bold, 
    style=normal,
    align=flushleft,
    alternative=hanging, 
    width=broad,
    margin=1cm,
  ]

\starttext
\startdescr{Para}
  This is a shorter item label, and some text that talks about it.
  The text is wrapped into a paragraph, with successive lines indented.

  This is another paragraph under the "Para" item.
  \startdescr{Sub Item}  
    This is a description of an item which is within the "Para" item.
  \stopdescr
  \startdescr{Sub Item} 
    Another Sub Item 
  \stopdescr
\stopdescr
\startdescr{Short}
  A short item that's not part of that really long "Para" item.
\stopdescr

\stoptext
```

and yields text formatted schematically like this:

```
Para   This is a shorter item label, and some text that
    talks about it.  The text is wrapped into a paragraph,
    with successive lines indented.
    This is another paragraph under the "Para" item.

    Sub Item   This is a description of an item which
         is within the "Para" item.

    Sub Item   Another Sub Item.

Short    A short item that's not part of that really long
    "Para" item.
```

What I'm looking for is as follows:

```
Para   
    This is a shorter item label, and some text that talks
    about it.  The text is wrapped into a paragraph, with
    successive lines indented.
    This is another paragraph under the "Para" item.

    Sub Item
        This is a description of an item which is within
        the "Para" item.

    Sub Item
        Another Sub Item.

Short
    A short item that's not part of that really long
    "Para" item.
```

I've tried all kinds of things, using the 'command', 'before', 'inbetween', 'after', 'headcommand' options of \definedescription (see http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setupdescriptions), with \crlf, \par, \vspace, but nothing I tried gave the desired effect.

Answer (score 4):

To place the title of your description before the content you have to use `alternative=top` in the setup. As the title is indented by the same amount as the content when you use the `margin` key you have to move it to the left with the `\offset` which is applied with the `headcommand` key.

```
\define[1]\DescriptionHeadCommand
  {\offset[leftoffset=-1cm]{#1}}

\definedescription
  [descr]
  [alternative=top,
   margin=1cm,
   headcommand=\DescriptionHeadCommand]

\showframe[text][text]

\starttext

\startdescr{Knuth}
\input knuth
\stopdescr

\stoptext
```

[image: Description with title on the top.]

Comment: This specific example works for me, but if I use the same technique in my giant document then all labels show up as literal text #1 -- except if I place the `\DescriptionHeadCommand` definition at the very beginning of the document.

Comment: Maybe you’re using `\asciimode` in your document which would explain this.

Comment: That was an excellent deduction: the document does call `\asciimode`, and the solution works if I place it before that call.